# After getting a post with a collection of comments on the same page, how do I add a new comment in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

After finding out from Ursus yesterday about how to get the list of comments for a given post, I was able to modify the post/show.html.erb page to show the post information and the list ( as yet empty ) of comments for that post on that page.  However, I am at a loss about how to then add a 'Add Comment' link to that page that would bring up the comment form and set the id of the post into the comments post-id field.  The example I was using said to get rid of the entire Views/comments directory, but this leaves me no show page for entering the Comment data.  Below is the top portion of the post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end
```

and here is the top portion of the comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here is the posts/show.html.erb page that shows the post and the list of comments table:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<p>
  <strong>ID:</strong>
  <%= @post.id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Body:</strong>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>


<hr/>
<h1>Comments</h1>

<table id="posts-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Body</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr >
        <td><%= comment.name %></td>
        <td><%= comment.body %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<hr/>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Add Comment', new_comment_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#posts-table").dataTable();
  });
</script>
```

I'm confused about several items:

1. where does new_comment_path come from and does the @post contain the id needed for creating the comment and linking it to the post?
2. Do I need a views/comments/show.html.erb page to put the form for the comment on?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where does new_comment_path come from and does the @post contain the
>   id needed for creating the comment and linking it to the post?

It comes from /config/routes.rb. `Resources` is a keyword that defines typical

```
new_comment_path, comment_path, comments_path, etc.
```

Yes, @post contains the ID.

> Do I need a views/comments/show.html.erb page to put the form for the
>   comment on?

You can if you wish, you are not obligated to show anything or add any forms in a Rails application. Many Rails applications are configured like this: `views/comments/_form.html.erb` and will render the form as a partial anywhere it is needed.

You can place forms anywhere. Don't forget that at the end of the day, you're just serving HTML. Rails *seems* special because it has some preset configurations regarding the mapping of controller actions to views. But you're allowed to do anything you want.

eg.

```
# inside ANY controller
def show
  @comment = Comment.first
  render 'comments/show.html.erb'
end
```

That's completely valid, albeit a really bad practice. But in Rails, you're not tied down by any of its configurations. They just exist to make coding a web app faster and easier.

Comment: With new in comments controller defined as comment = Comment.new, and that allows me to fill in the form from the partial for the form it then somehow goes to the create action which starts with post = Post.find(params[:id]), and then comment = post.comments.create(comment_params).  But, it get couldn't find post without an id.  How do I get the id of the post available to the create action so the comment can be added to the post collection? ( Add at sign where appropriate)

Comment: You might want to review [this article](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3681-Complex-Forms-in-Rails-5). Essentially, a has_many relationship (as I assume a Post has_many Comments) allows you to nest form fields. Alternatively, sometimes I'll just put a hidden input field in my form with the @post.id already set as the value of the field called :post_id. When a user submits, I can grab that from the params. But I try to follow Rails conventions when possible. Usually, when you're manually grabbing and setting special params from a form, you're probably missing a better Rails convention.

Comment: Really appreciate the help.  I looked at the article, but could not see how to apply it to my situation.  I find that if I hard wire in the 'at'post = Post.find('2'), i.e. the id of the second post, the comment is added correctly to the Post.  I have the belongs_to and has_many statements as you stated.  I still can't get the id of the post into the comments_controller so that I can find the selected post.  I tried fields on the various forms, but they still were not found.  Fundamental misunderstanding of where to put what.

Comment: Okay I'm doing this on mobile and you definitely are struggling.  Just put a hidden field called post_id and set a value of post.id in it. Then bit submit and look at the params in your method. Do you see a post_id? You should or you didn't do that correctly.

Comment: I appreciate your patience.  In the show view for the post I have
<%= link_to 'Add Comment', :controller => 'comments', :action => 'new', :id =>(at)post.id %> .  In the partial for the comment I have:   <div class="field">
    <%= form.label 'post_id' %>
    <%= form.text_field :post_id, :value => "#@id" %>
  </div>
  
to try to show the id passed in and pass it as post_id.  This shows in console as:
Started GET "/comments/new?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 
Processing by CommentsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Then comments/new.html.erb & _form.  
 Field shows blank

Comment: I don't think you understand... Forms submit data. `link_to` is NOT a submission of a form. That is an anchor tag in HTML. That links to another page. I used Codepen (for simplicities sake) show share [this code sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moQOYM). What I want you to do is stop commenting on this thread as it's unhelpful. You need to stop and sit and think. What is a form in HTML? How do forms work? What is a POST versus a GET request? When should I make a POST request (as you incorrectly made a GET)? You have skipped over the basics which make this far more complex than need be.